# Extending Lie algebra homomorphisms.

Tags: rt.representation-theory, reference-request

Let $\frak g$ be a Lie algebra over a field of characteristic zero with a Lie subalgebra $\frak s$ and consider $M$ a $\frak s$-module. When is it possible to extend the action of $\frak s$ to $\frak g$, i.e give a $\frak g$-module structure to $M$?

Notice that I stated $\frak g$ without dimensional restrictions. However, my problem is specifically working with $\frak g \otimes \mathbb C [ t,t^{-1}]$, where $\frak g$ is a finite dimensional Lie algebra over $\mathbb C$.

Here I don't care how the action is extended, I am only interested in existencial stuff.

What could be a good reference to dealt with this problem?

Comment: Any book on the representation theory of Lie algebras would persuade you that the answer is no in general. 

Comment: @Simon: I will edit the question to avoid further problems.

Answer (score 3):

For finite-dimensional Lie algebras, see e.g. the papers [Extensions of Representations of Lie Groups and Lie Algebras, I](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2372443) by G. Hochschild and G.D. Mostow ([part II](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2372788) by Mostow is mostly on Lie groups), [Extensions of representations of algebraic linear groups](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2373191) by A. Białynicki-Birula and the two preceding authors, and [Extensions of representations of Lie algebras](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102699676) by J.G. Ryan. The key words 'extension(s) of representations' will land you a number of other references upon searching in Google or MathSciNet. For loop algebras, which you are interested in, some results can be found in the paper  [Extensions of modules over loop algebras](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2374946) by Fialowski and Malikov and in [this recent preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.4367) by E. Neher and A. Savage.